# How to control the flow of function execution in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have written some code in the AngularJS controller.
The scene is as follow, I have a form which accepts all the details of the **Organization** including its name, its admin etc. I have written manual validations to validate the data. I have written a separate function to validate the data. Which validates all the data and depending upon the validations function return **"true/false"**, I want to check the returned value and if the value is **'true'**, I want to make a call to service to enter the data into the database, **BUT**, If the result is **false** I am not supposed to call the service and show the proper alert message. **BUT THE PROBLEM IS**, The place from where I am calling validation function, it does not wait for function to return the value, instead It gets executed first and then the value is returned to the calling function, as a result it always shows the status as **"undefined"**.

**Validation function is as follows:**

```
 $scope.validateOrganizationForm = function(){

          var phoneNumber = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;  

         if($scope.organization.orgName == "" || $scope.organization.orgName.length > 16){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization name of length between 1 to 16");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgAddress == "" || $scope.organization.orgAddress.length > 512){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization address of length between 1 to 512");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgPhoneNumber == "" || $scope.organization.orgPhoneNumber.length>13 || (!($scope.organization.orgPhoneNumber.match(phoneNumber)))){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization phone number of length between 10 to 13");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgAlternatePhoneNumber != "" && ($scope.organization.orgAlternatePhoneNumber.length>13 ||  (!($scope.organization.orgAlternatePhoneNumber.match(phoneNumber)))) ){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization alternate phone number of length between 10 to 13");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgContactPersonName == "" || $scope.organization.orgContactPersonName.length > 64){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization contact person name of length between 1 to 64");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgContactPersonPhoneNumber == "" ||  (!($scope.organization.orgContactPersonPhoneNumber.match(phoneNumber)))){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization contact person phone number of length between 10 to 13");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgContactPersonEmailId == "" || $scope.organization.orgContactPersonEmailId == undefined || $scope.organization.orgContactPersonEmailId.length > 64){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization contact person email id of length between 1 to 64");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.orgDescription == "" || $scope.organization.orgDescription.length > 256){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization description of length between 1 to 256");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.userVo.username == "" || $scope.organization.userVo.username.length > 64){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization admin username of length between 1 to 64");
             return false;
         }else if($scope.organization.userVo.emailId == "" || $scope.organization.userVo.emailId.length > 128){
             $scope.failureAlertMessage("Please enter valid organization admin email Id of length between 1 to 128");
             return false;
         }else{
             console.log("All the fields are validated except validating duplications, lets check it now");
             $scope.checkOrgName().then(
                     function(orgNameStatus){
                         console.log("can we use this org name :"+orgNameStatus);
                         if(orgNameStatus==false){
                             console.log("Organziation name is already present in the database");
                             return false;
                         }else if(orgNameStatus){
                             $scope.isOrgAdminUsernameAvailable = $scope.checkOrgAdminUsername().then(
                                     function(orgAdminUsernameStatus){
                                         console.log("Can we use this username for admin: "+orgAdminUsernameStatus);
                                         if(orgAdminUsernameStatus == false){
                                             console.log("org admin username is already present in the database");
                                             return false;
                                         }else if(orgAdminUsernameStatus){
                                             $scope.isAdminEmailIdAvailable = $scope.checkOrgAdminEmailId().then(
                                                     function(orgAdminemailIdStatus){
                                                         console.log("Can we use this admin email id: "+orgAdminemailIdStatus);
                                                         if(orgAdminemailIdStatus == false){
                                                             console.log("Org admin email id is already present in the database");
                                                             return false;
                                                         }else if(orgAdminemailIdStatus){
                                                             console.log("All the three fields(orgName,orgAdminUsername,orgAdminEmailId) are checked for duplication, everything is validated sucessfully");
                                                             return true;
                                                         }
                                                     });
                                         }
                                     });
                         }
                     });
         }
         return true;
     }
```

**And here is the calling function:**

```
$scope.addOrganization = function(){
         console.log("Command in add Org");
         var validationStatus = $scope.validateOrganizationForm(); (Here I am calling validation function)

                     console.log("Add form validation status: "+validationStatus); (This always gives me undefined...)
                     if(validationStatus){
                         console.log("Form validated successfully, We can add organization safely");
                         OrganizationService.addOrganization($scope.organization).then(
                            function(data){
                                $scope.successAlertMessage("Organition Added successfully");
                                $scope.resetAddOrgForm();
                            },
                            function(errResponse){
                                $scope.successAlertMessage("There was an error adding organization");
                            }
                         );
                     }else{
                         console.log("Add form validation failed");
                     }


      }
```

Can I use **.then()** for this, I tried that too, but it says I am not returning any promise instead I am just returning a plain boolean value, How can I send the promise if I have to use **.then()**..??

Comment: First, you should use the built-in form validation of angular (using ng-required, ng-maxlength, etc.). This would already cut the code in half, and would give instantaneous feedback to the user. Second, you need to understand promises and asynchronism. You can't return a boolean value from an asynchronous validation method. That can't possibly work. read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. What you can return is a promise of boolean.

Comment: In the if statement you can call your function as if($scope.validateOrganizationForm()){ }

Comment: No, That did not worked @pritesh

Comment: @JB Nizet, I know that I should have used inbuilt validator of the angular js, but I used this approach because I had to match the look to the previous version of the system as per Client's request, Anyways, Can you suggest me anything in my code itself....

Comment: Yes, I suggest you read the article I linked to, to try realizing that you can't return a boolean from an asynchronous method, and understand how promises work.

Comment: Okay I will read that thoroughly, Thanx for the quick response..!!